# Azure Error : unauthorized: aad access token with sp failed client id must be guid

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-pipelines, devops

I am trying to create a NodeJS Azure pipeline, deployed to a container and publish it. While pushing the container I got the following error. I am using a **Guest User** account with **Contributor** permission. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like an issue with the Service connection. Try creating a new service connection (service principal) and push the image. You might need to have elevated permission for creating a Service principal.